# Angular 2 Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular, typescript1.6

I have read several articles on dependency injection and cannot seem to get it working the way I think it should. From what I have read, you can use the @Injectable decorator on a class and then the metadata is created for the DI like so:

```js
import {Hero} from './hero.model';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Hero Service Created');
    }
}
```

Then in your component, you can use it in your constructor (with the proper import) like this:

```js
constructor(heroService: HeroService) {
    console.log('App Component Created');
}
```

However, I get the following error: Cannot resolve all parameters for AppComponent(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.

I am able to get it working properly if I remove the @Injectable syntax from the service and instead have my constructor like this:

```js
constructor(@Inject(HeroService) heroService: HeroService) {
    console.log('App Component Created');
}
```

With everything that I've read, these should do the same thing, but they aren't. Any ideas as to why? I am using Typescript 1.6.2 with VS 2013, angular 2 v2.0.0-alpha.46, and systemjs v0.19.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you've specified "emitDecoratorMetadata" option in your TypeScript configuration.

Comment: That's the only thing I could think of too. @Rob here's a basic plunker with a simple service with working DI. The Cars Component uses the cars service. http://plnkr.co/edit/8ILuwhtxAP3g9o6u6jAQ?p=preview

Comment: This got me going in the right direction. Since I am developing within visual studio and having it compile my TS files, I had to add this to my csproj file:
<TypeScriptAdditionalFlags> $(TypeScriptAdditionalFlags) --emitDecoratorMetadata </TypeScriptAdditionalFlags>

Comment: Better yet, instead, add this to your csproj file so that it will compile on save and not just on build:
<TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>true</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>